# Pronunciation of "Formulæ"

Tags: classical-latin, pronunciation, vulgar-latin

What is the pronunciation of **Formulæ** in Latin ?

Is there any difference (in pronunciation) between classical and vulgar Latin ?

The answer can be in International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA) format.

Comment: Welcome to the site! There are some Latin pronunciation resources on this site and elsewhere across the internet. Have you tried checking any? I assume the downvote you got has to do with asking for quite a lot (a sound file) while showing none of your own attempts to figure this out. Do you really mean vulgar Latin and not ecclesiastical Latin or something else? If you have a specific context in mind where you want to use this, please edit it in and we can help figure out the correct pronunciation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joonas. The context is: I am the creator of an open source project named Fōrmulæ (please note the ō with macron, it was intended to be different to Formulæ, a well known word, but based on it). [link](http://formulae.org/) Of course I know that the origin of the word is Latin and also its meaning. I have already searched about the pronunciation, but I recurrently get the "English" pronunciation of the word. I don't know much about Latin but I am certainly sure that many sounds of English were not present in Latin, so the original Latin pronunciation could be very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***formŭla , ae***

The tonal accent is on the first syllable as in English.

*for-* the *-r-* should be heard; *o* as in note/ Fr. nôtre.

*-mŭ-*  short 'u' as in 'foot' (no intrusive *y,* or *j* )

*-lae*  *ae* as 'ai' in aisle; *[ae* becomes *e,* 'é' in mediaeval L. *]*.

(This answer is based on a 1960 schoolbook; choirmasters, revisionists, recidivists, and historians have ruined my ear for any 'correct' pronunciation)